# Set Name of and access individual CustomControls in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf

I am writing a programme with C#, .NET 4.6 and WPF. I would like to have a set of CustomControls arranged in a two-dimensional grid (size dynamically specified at runtime) and be able to access each CustomControl.

I did some research, found different pieces of information about the ItemsControl, and created a solution which to some extend does what I want.
Here are the relevant parts of the code, they compile and run.

XAML for CustomControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding MyFill1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MyUserControl}}">
        </Rectangle>
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MyUserControl}}" >
            </TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

code-behind for CustomControl

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyText1Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyText1", 
                                        typeof(String), typeof(MyUserControl),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(""));

        public String MyText1
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(MyText1Property); }
            set { SetValue(MyText1Property, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyFill1Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyFill1",
                                        typeof(SolidColorBrush),
                                        typeof(MyUserControl),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)));

        public SolidColorBrush MyFill1
        {
            get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(MyFill1Property); }
            set { SetValue(MyFill1Property, value); }
        }


        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML for hosting MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Name="MyMainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="MyItemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding ElementName=MyMainWindow, Path=UniformGridColumns, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:MyUserControl MyText1="{Binding Text1}" MyFill1="{Binding Fill1}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

code-behind for hosting main window

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public int UniformGridColumns  //number of columns of the grid
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(UniformGridColumnsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UniformGridColumnsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty UniformGridColumnsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UniformGridColumns", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((int)0));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.DataContext = this;
            Setup(13, 5); //13 columns, 5 rows
        }

        public void Setup(int columns, int rows) //setup the grid
        {
            UniformGridColumns = columns;
            SingleControl[] singleControls = new SingleControl[rows*columns];

            for (int i = 0; i < rows*columns; i++)
                singleControls[i] = new SingleControl()
                {
                    Text1 = (i/ columns + 1) + ", " + (i % columns + 1),
                    Fill1 = new SolidColorBrush((i % 2 != 0) ? Colors.Yellow : Colors.Red)
                }; //example, display position in grid and fill with two different colours

            MyItemsControl.ItemsSource = singleControls.ToList<SingleControl>();
        }

        public MyUserControl GetSingleControl(int column, int row)  //access a single control
        {
            //some code involving VisualTreeHelper
            return null;
        }

        private class SingleControl  //helper class for setting up the grid
        {
            public String Text1 { get; set; }
            public Brush Fill1 { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

The method MainWindow.Setup(int, int) fills the ItemControl with the desired number of MyCustomControls, I can label and fill them with any colour I want.

Question 1:
How can I implement GetSingleControl(int, int) that returns the MyCustomControl on the specified position? I started with a solution involving  VisualTreeHelper which seems to be clumsy and unflexible.

Question 2:
How can I set Name of all MyCustomControls, e.g. something like "MyCustomControl_01_05" for the item in row 1 and column 5.

Question 3:
If questions 1 and 2 cannot be answered on the basis of my solution, what would be a more suitable approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Wanting to name and access some controls within an ItemsControl sounds akward if not wrong. You normally don't access and maniuplate the GUI elements directly in code-behind, but rather bind the GUI elements to some ViewModels (the items in the ItemsControl.ItemsSource collection), manipulate those ViewModels in code-behind and WPF's binding mechanism will then let the GUI elements respond/update without your code caring about the dirty details and complex dynamics and hierarchy/layout of the GUI elements.

Comment: You should extend your research to mvvm.  ( Which is what elgonzo is describing).  Your dependency properties look like they might be unnecessary. For example a usercontrol already has a background property you could bind. You can also just datatemplate out UI with no usercontrol at all.

Comment: Thanks. I already suspected that MVVM is a good idea here. I was hesitating because it comes with an overhead and this is a minor project only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give an example of what both elgonzo and Andy said, you should change things to be more MVVM friendly. Once you do more research you will understand why you dont want to bother with the DependencyProperties, binding to the code behind, and manually coding all the additions of the usercontrols. 
This could be made pretty or more streamlined, but i coded it to give a full example of how this could be done with MVVM. I tried to make it simple and basic, while demonstrating how to refactor your idea.

New MainWindow.xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="MyMainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Name="MyItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding GridRow}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding GridColumn}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding ColumnCount}" Rows="{Binding RowCount}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Fill1}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

New MainWindow.xaml.cs (Notice there is no extra code)

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       
 }
```

Add a file MainWindowViewModel.cs: 
 -note the MyElement could be abstracted to a viewmodel for a UserControl if you desire.

```
public class MyElement : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyElement()
    {
        //some default data for design testing
        Text1 = "Test";
        Fill1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        GridColumn = 13;
        GridRow = 5;
    }
    private string _text1;
    public string Text1
    {
        get { return _text1; }
        set{
            if (value != _text1) { _text1 = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }

    private Brush _fill1;
    public Brush Fill1
    {
        get { return _fill1; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _fill1) { _fill1 = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }
    private int _gridRow;
    public int GridRow
    {
        get { return _gridRow; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _gridRow) { _gridRow = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }

    private int _gridColumn;
    public int GridColumn
    {
        get { return _gridColumn; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _gridColumn) { _gridColumn = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel() : this(13, 5) { }

    public MainWindowViewModel(int columns, int rows)
    {
        ColumnCount = columns;
        RowCount = rows;

        MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyElement>();

        //your original setup code
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            {
                var vm = new MyElement
                {
                    Text1 = (i / columns + 1) + ", " + (i % columns + 1),
                    Fill1 = new SolidColorBrush((i % 2 != 0) ? Colors.Yellow : Colors.Red),
                    GridColumn = i,
                    GridRow = j
                };
                MyList.Add(vm);
            }
        }
    }

    private int _rowCount;
    public int RowCount
    {
        get { return _rowCount; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _rowCount) { _rowCount = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }

    private int _columnCount;
    public int ColumnCount
    {
        get { return _columnCount; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _columnCount) { _columnCount = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MyElement> MyList { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I did a more full solution where it uses INotifyPropertyChanged. I wont explain the reason for using it (in the event you are unaware), as there are much better explanations you can quickly search for.

I also made it so all the dynamic information uses Binding to make things easier to change. Now the Grid size, and item positioning are bound to your data. So it should adjust automatically as you change your "MyElement"

This should give you a good starting point for refactoring your code, and help you utilize what WPF was designed to do, as there are many mechanisms built in so you dont have to hard code UI layer manipulation (as you were in the code behind)

This also answers your Questions:

Q1 : You can now just access to the List of MyElements and change them accordingly. The UI layer should update automatically when you change anything.

Q2 : You shouldnt need to do this now, as each MyElement will keep a property for it's Grid Position. Thus you can just access that.

Comment: Indeed, a good starting point and just what I expected. Thank you!